# std::experimental::optional with ndk/clang

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, c++14, c++-experimental

I am trying to build my project which uses `std::experimental::optional`. For Linux it compiled just fine, but for android/ndk the compiler throws:

`error: no member named 'experimental' in namespace 'std'`

I am building with the [polly](https://github.com/ruslo/polly) toolchain `android-ndk-r17-api-24-armeabi-v7a-clang-libcxx14` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`

```
# Copyright (c) 2015-2018, Ruslan Baratov
# Copyright (c) 2017-2018, Robert Nitsch
# Copyright (c) 2018, David Hirvonen
# All rights reserved.

if(DEFINED POLLY_ANDROID_NDK_R17_API_24_ARMEABI_V7A_CLANG_LIBCXX14_CMAKE_)
  return()
else()
  set(POLLY_ANDROID_NDK_R17_API_24_ARMEABI_V7A_CLANG_LIBCXX14_CMAKE_ 1)
endif()

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/utilities/polly_clear_environment_variables.cmake")

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/utilities/polly_init.cmake")

set(ANDROID_NDK_VERSION "r17")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION "24")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI "armeabi-v7a")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_NEON TRUE)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE TRUE) # 32-bit ARM
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION "clang")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE "c++_static") # LLVM libc++ static

polly_init(
    "Android NDK ${ANDROID_NDK_VERSION} / \
API ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION} / ${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} / \
Clang / c++14 support / libc++ static"
    "Unix Makefiles"
)

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/utilities/polly_common.cmake")

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/flags/cxx14.cmake") # before toolchain!

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/os/android.cmake")
```

I tried to build a minimal example:

```
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::experimental::optional<int> b = 6;
    std::cout << b.value()  <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but it builds just fine with the same toolchain.

I apologize, that I cannot post my code here. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Have a read of https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/609  Looks like it is still an open issue.

Comment: Thanks, that explains my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update to NDK r19 and just use `std::optional`. It's not experimental in C++17.